# Problems with Reachability in iOS 5.1?

Tags: iphone

We were using Apple's Reachability a few months ago to check for the network status of the iPad.  It worked before.  Now when I try to test for it, I always get network unreachable and am wondering why.  Any thoughts on this?  Here's some of my code:

```
// In the class I want to check for reachability to send email from, I access my singleton object WebServiceManager
WebServiceManager *wmgr = [WebServiceManager sharedInstance];
[wmgr CheckNetworkStatus];

if (wmgr.isInternetAvailable) {        
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *mailNotConfiguredAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"This device is not configured to send mail" message:@"Please set up your mail account in order to send an email." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [mailNotConfiguredAlert show];
        [mailNotConfiguredAlert release];
    }
}
else {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Network Connection Unavailable" message:@"The network connection is currently unavailable.  Please try again later." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];      
}
```

// In WebServiceManager

```
- (void)CheckNetworkStatus {
NetworkStatus internetStatus = [_networkReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
switch (internetStatus)
{
    case NotReachable:
    {
        isInternetAvailable = NO;
        break;
    }
    case ReachableViaWiFi:
    {
        isInternetAvailable = YES;
        break;
    }
    case ReachableViaWWAN:
    {
        isInternetAvailable = YES;
        break;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it's not Reachability, we're using it in 5.1 at the moment and it doesn't produce any weird behavior.

Check if your boolean property `isInternetAvailable` is being set properly (probably some `NSLog` debugging would help).